# Combining results of select queries without using set operators(UNION)

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible without using union operator combining results of queries in sql (which works same as union/union all)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's suppose you have two tables you want to `UNION`

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(`id` int, `name` varchar(32));
CREATE TABLE Table2
(`id` int, `name` varchar(32));
```

And sample data

table1:

```
| ID |  NAME |
|----|-------|
|  1 | name1 |
|  2 | name2 |
|  3 | name3 |
```

table2:

```
| ID |  NAME  |
|----|--------|
| 11 | name11 |
| 22 | name22 |
| 33 | name33 |
|  1 |  name1 |
```

To emulate `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) id,
       COALESCE(t1.name, t2.name) name
  FROM 
(
  SELECT TABLE_NAME <> 'table1' n
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = SCHEMA()
     AND TABLE_NAME IN('table1', 'table2')
) t LEFT JOIN table1 t1 
    ON t.n = 0 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t.n = 1
```

Output:

```
| ID |   NAME |
|----|--------|
|  1 |  name1 |
|  2 |  name2 |
|  3 |  name3 |
| 11 | name11 |
| 22 | name22 |
| 33 | name33 |
|  1 |  name1 |
```

To emulate `UNION` you need just to add `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) id,
       COALESCE(t1.name, t2.name) name
  FROM 
(
  SELECT TABLE_NAME <> 'table1' n
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = SCHEMA()
     AND TABLE_NAME IN('table1', 'table2')
) t LEFT JOIN table1 t1 
    ON t.n = 0 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t.n = 1
```

Output:

```
| ID |   NAME |
|----|--------|
|  1 |  name1 |
|  2 |  name2 |
|  3 |  name3 |
| 11 | name11 |
| 22 | name22 |
| 33 | name33 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa6e5/2)** demo

Comment: +1 - It took me some time to grasp what *(and why)* you were using the information schemes. Very nice solution.

Comment: awesome, it was really easy understanding it!

Answer (score 0):

we tried and got the simple query but i don't know how efficient is this .

```
CREATE TABLE tableA
  ( col1 INTEGER , col2 INTEGER
  );
CREATE TABLE tableB
  ( col1 INTEGER , col2 INTEGER
  )

// insert statements
INSERT INTO tableA
  (COL1, COL2
  ) VALUES
  (12, 13
  );
INSERT INTO tableA
  (COL1, COL2
  ) VALUES
  (14, 15
  );
INSERT INTO tableB
  (COL1, COL2
  ) VALUES
  (12, 13
  );
INSERT INTO tableB
  (COL1, COL2
  ) VALUES
  (14, 15
  );

// for union all
SELECT (
  CASE
    WHEN b.col1 IS NULL
    THEN a.col1
    ELSE b.col1
  END)
FROM
  (SELECT COL1 FROM TableB
  )b
FULL OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT COL1 FROM TableA
  ) a
ON 1=2

// for union
SELECT (
  CASE
    WHEN b.col1 IS NULL
    THEN a.col1
    WHEN b.col1=a.col1
    THEN b.col1
    ELSE b.col1
  END)
FROM
  (SELECT COL1 FROM TableB
  )b
FULL OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT COL1 FROM TableA
  ) a
ON a.col1=b.col1
```

Comment: please share ur valuable comments

Comment: Your original question was tagged with MySQL and there is no implementation for `FULL JOIN` in MySQL

Comment: yes i agree... but we can use full outer join there also in MySQL but syntax will differ I think

Comment: @Basu Given your original requirements your own answer is incorrect, because MySql has no `FULL OUTER JOIN` unless you have other solution for MySql. It doesn't go well with the SO rules. To ask one question, then give answer for another and unaccept the answer that were given to your original set of requirements...

Comment: Okay sorry ,I mentioned MySql by mistake.