# CONCAT IDs as the last record

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to create a MySQL query wherein we can concat all the ids of the selected records and add it as the last record of the query? The first column of the last record will contain the CONCAT of the ids and the rest of the columns will be blank.

```
ID | name | age | gender
-------------------------
1  | John | 25  | Male
-------------------------
2  | Ron  | 32  | Male
-------------------------
3  | Ann  | 41  | Female
-------------------------
4  | Harry| 23  | Male     <----------- Last record
-------------------------
1,2,3,4|  |     |          <----------- Concatenated IDS (Comma Separated)
```

Is this possible? Without UNION?

Comment: Why can't you use `UNION`?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18605399/2203084) might help with the `UNION` issue.

Comment: Why do that in SQL? SQL is for manipulating data, not formatting it.

Comment: So only UNION is the possible way and nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,name,age,gender FROM t
UNION
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ID ORDER BY ID),'','','' FROM t
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that we don't need to use UNION.

Comment: @kimbarcelona You can avoid union but it would be extremely convoluted and unmaintainable.